# Can I restore gpg private key from raw data to enigmail?

Tags: gnupg, data-recovery, enigmail

I have recovered data from my local storage. The most valuable for me was to recover the private gpg key. I have found it in raw data files, I did delimitation based on the headers and footers. Now I have two separate *.key files with private key files content. How can I use it to rebuild my gpg keys, which I can use in Enigmail?

Answer (score 1):

You could first get your public key from your private key like this:

```
  $ gpg --import private.key
  $ gpg --export $ID > public.key
```

Where you can determine the $ID of your key as follows:

```
$ gpg --list-keys
```

Afterwards you can import your key pair into Enigmail via *File → Import Keys From File* (as described in the Enigmail Wiki [1]).

[1] https://enigmail.wiki/Key_Management#Importing_an_existing_key_pair